# How to multiply an array by a percentage?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am having some difficulties finishing my code. It's working perfectly except I can't figure out how to multiply my array of numbers by a percentage. Here is my code:

```
<p>Click the button to get the sum of the numbers in the array.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p>Sum of numbers in array: <span id="demo"></span></p>

<p>Amount with 7% tax added: <span id="percent"></span></p>
<script>
var numbers = [12.3, 20, 30.33];

function getSum(total, num) {
    return total + num;
}
function myFunction(item) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = numbers.reduce(getSum);
}

function myFunction(item) {
    document.getElementById("percent").innerHTML = (numbers * .07);
}

</script>
```

All help is appreciated!

Comment: You need to get the sum first and then calculate the percentage `numbers.reduce(getSum) * .07`

Comment: As mentioned above you need to first sum elements, then multiply (if not than you are not multiplying numbers, which is weird for anyone, JS included).
You may also want to create another array with all items being multiplied by tax rate with Array.prototype.forEach() method. 

Btw, regardless of coding problems. Multiplying it by 0.07 will give you tax amount, not amount with tax added. You want to multiply it by 1.07.

Answer (score 1):

As you ask just how to multiply ( and I assume you want 7%) the answer would be

```
var numbers = [12.3, 20, 30.33];

numbers = numbers.map(function(i){
  return Math.round(i*.07 * 100)/100;
});

console.log(numbers);
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiply with an array always results `NaN`. I think You need to get the `7%` of the total sum then get the sum first and then calculate the percentage by multiplying.

```
numbers.reduce(getSum) * .07
```

```html
<p>Click the button to get the sum of the numbers in the array.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p>Sum of numbers in array: <span id="demo"></span>
</p>

<p>Amount with 7% tax added: <span id="percent"></span>
</p>
<script>
  var numbers = [12.3, 20, 30.33];

  function getSum(total, num) {
    return total + num;
  }

  function myFunction(item) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = numbers.reduce(getSum);
  }

  function myFunction(item) {
    document.getElementById("percent").innerHTML = numbers.reduce(getSum) * .07;
  }
</script>
```